# WCF: which kind of exception to handle

Tags: .net, wcf, exception, fault

In WCF service, I will have exception happening.

I've the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults attribute in the serviceDebug behavior.

if I've a method declared like this:

```
[OperationContract]
String SayHello(String name);
```

And let's imagine that I do something that generate a NullReferenceException in this SayHello method.

On the **client** side, what will I receive?
A `FaultException` or a `NullReferenceException`?

I can't find any documentation on this.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client should receive a faultexception, always - as its a soap fault... If you want further detail, you can add this to your operation contract:
`[FaultContract(typeof(NullReferenceException))]` and then you can catch it like this:

```
}catch(FaultException<NullReferenceException> e){...
```

Comment: Ok thank you. It was just a theorical case, thank you very much. I had the response that I wanted.